# Best way to include a well-formed (untyped) json in ASP.NET API Response

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Building a Web API in ASP.NET Core.
I have a controller operation that receives a request (an object with a `byte[]`) and in the response it should return a JSON value that is dynamically generated (it's a parsing operation). So, I cannot strong type the object in the response, because it depends on the request.

The response class I have, is looking like the following:

```cs
public class ConversionResponse
{
    public string Json { get; set; }
}
```

The operation implementation looks like this (slimmed down):

```cs
[HttpGet()]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConvertFile(ConversionRequest request)
{
    // This just gets a json string (in my case an array, but could be any json string)
    string json = await GetJsonAsync(request);
    return Ok(new ConversionResponse{Json = json });
}
```

The result I get is like the following (where the json value is serialized to a string)

```json
{
    "json": "[{\"Column1\":\"Value1\",\"Column2\":\"Value2\"},{\"Column1\":\"Value4\",\"Column2\":\"Value5\"}]"
}
```

The result I hope for, is the following

```json
{
    "json": [{"Column1":"Value1","Column2":"Value2"},{"Column1":"Value4","Column2":"Value5"}]
}
```

I have tried to parse the `json` string to a `JObject` or `JToken` and include that instead of a `string` in the response object, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any help to solve this, is highly appreciated!

Comment: can I understand your requirement as : convert json string to json object? If so, you shouldn't define `public string Json { get; set; }` in ConversionResponse class, you already define it as the string, so it has to be a string.

Comment: Does `GetJsonAsync()` end with a step creating a (JSON) string from some object? That may be where your problem begins, how about returning the object instead?

Comment: (updated the question/code to indicate it's a string)

Comment: It's not a typed class, so return an object did not work (had empty array).  I have also tried `dynamic`, `JToken` and `JObject`, but they got serialization errors.

Comment: `"[{\"Column1\":\"Value1\",\"Column2\":\"Value2\"},{\"Column1\":\"Value4\",\"Column2\":\"Value5\"}]"` -> this is `array string`, but not `json string`, pls make sure what you are trying to convert is a json string so that you could avoid serialization error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your sample, you are defining `public string Json { get; set; }` in `ConversionResponse` class which should result in returning `{"json":"string content here"}`.

Then what you want to return is `{"json" : [ ]}`, so that the value of parameter `json` is an array. But now what we have is an array string. So the easiest way to get the required returned data should be converting the `array string` to an `json object`. I used code like below:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string arrayString = "[{\"Column1\":\"Value1\",\"Column2\":\"Value2\"},{\"Column1\":\"Value4\",\"Column2\":\"Value5\"}]";
string formatString = string.Concat("{\"json\":", arrayString, "}");
JObject jsonObj1 = JObject.Parse(formatString);
JObject jsonObj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(formatString);
var val1 = jsonObj1["json"][0]["Column1"];
var val2 = jsonObj2["json"][1]["Column1"];
```

Just like you see, I convert the array string to json string first, then convert json string to json object. And if we just want to return the whole json object, we can `return Ok(formatString);` directly. As in the frontend, we can define the response as json, then the json string would be converted to json object automatically. We can also add `[Produces("application/json")]` in front of the controller action to convert the json string to json object as well. If we require to `return Ok(jsonObj2);`, then it demands to have `builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` in program.cs